# Do multiple processes may run in parallel on a multi thread single core CPU?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu

I know that there is some shared resources like L2 cache, etc between threads so is that two threads on the same core can run instructions from different processes in parallel ?

Comment: In addition to Alexei answer, I would recommand Arstechnica really good article: [introduction to multithreading](https://arstechnica.com/features/2002/10/hyperthreading/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the question of terminology. Hardware and software people use the same words differently. I understand your question as follows:

I know that there is some shared resources like L2 cache, etc between *hardware threads* so is that two *hardware threads* on the same core can run instructions from different *processes* in parallel ?

Then I translate hardware terms to software language:

I know that there is some shared resources like L2 cache, etc between *processors* so is that two *processors* on the same core can run instructions from different *software threads* in parallel ?

and immediately answer: yes, of course.

UPDT
"Does two software threads (from the same process) can be run on two different CPUs in parallel?"

yes, of course. Moreover, if each CPU consists of many cores, each core can serve separate software thread and so is indistinguishable from a processor. For example, my Intel i7 microchip has 4 cores/8 threads and standard Java function Runtime::availableProcessors() returns 8, that is, 8 separate software threads could be run in parallel. If my machine had 2 such microchips, it would return 16 and 16 separate threads could be run in parallel.

Comment: Yeah, I probably need to have some disambiguation to understand the difference between hardware thread and software thread. So the OS is responsible to distribute the software threads to the hardware ? Does two software threads (from the same process) can be run on two different CPUs in parallel? (On a multi CPU architecture). If so, do there is some overhead to have two software threads on different CPUs instead to have them running on the same CPU ?

Comment: two software threads on different CPUs compared to running on the same CPU (but different core/threads) may run faster or slower. If they use the same memory but different computational devices, then faster on the same CPU, but this happens rarely, so usually  threads on different CPUs run faster.